# Error in View : cannot coerce class ‘c("gg", "ggplot")’ to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

tried to find a solution for this Problem in other Posts, but couldn´t find a one helping me to solve my Problem, but I have to admit that this is actually my first time using R. I just want to view the plot "a" that so far always worked. Checking str(b) assures that a data frame is reported. Now I receive the mentioned error. I am still learning, so don´t hesitate to point out any mistake. Thanks a lot!

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
require(scales)
require(readxl)
library(labeling)
library(magrittr)
c <- read.csv2("Input/MRL_abrufe_2019.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)
c <- abrufe %>% 
  mutate("AUKTION" = hour(as.POSIXct(paste(abrufe$DATUM, abrufe$UHRZEIT.VON), format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")) %/% 4 + 1)

b <- c %>% 
  mutate(ABRUFDATUM = DATUM) %>% 
  select(-DATUM) %>%
  filter(BETR < 0) %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate("ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN" = (mrl_rel[mrl_rel$TAG == as.Date(ABRUFDATUM, format = "%d.%m.%Y") & mrl_rel$AUKTION == AUKTION,] %>% summarise(total = min(ARBEITSPREIS[KUMSUM >= abs(BETR)])))$total[1])

a <- ggplot(b %>% arrange(ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(N = 1:n(),"FILL" = case_when(ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN < 0 ~ "NEG", ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN >= 0 & ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN < 80 ~ "NULL", ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN >= 80 ~ "POS")), aes(x = N, y = ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN))+geom_line()+geom_point()
```

Comment: You probably tried to `View(a)`, maybe just by clicking on the environment pane.  You can't do that.  You can print it, by typing `a` in the console, and it will appear in the plot window.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want `print(a)` or just type `a` in the console.

#### Additional tips:

One starting point (since I don't have your data to check) is to restructure the code to separate the processing from the plotting.

```
b2 <- b %>%
  arrange(ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(
    N = 1:n(),
    "FILL" = case_when(
      ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN < 0 ~ "NEG",
      ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN >= 0 & ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN < 80 ~ "NULL",
      ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN >= 80 ~ "POS"
    )
  ) 

ggplot(b2, aes(x = N, y = ABRUFGRENZKOSTEN)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point()
```

Here I've created `b2` so you can check the additional transformations. This can then be used for the plotting steps. If you find that everything is working correctly you can rejoin these two like

```
b %>% 
 processing_steps %>%
 ggplot(aes(x, y)) + 
 geom_point()
```